# Largest Difference within a list of integers

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I've been trying to write a recursive function which takes a list of numbers such as [5;6;7;8;2;3;4] and returns 3 by finding the largest difference between sequences of ascending numbers in a list but have no idea where to go.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to with the "difference between sequences of numbers"?

Comment: e.g. 5-8 = 3 is the greatest difference in a sequence of ascending numbers in this list

Comment: you should give at least a small piece of code showing that you actually tried it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature should take the lowest number of the current sequence, the highest number of the current sequence and the remainding sequence. If the head of the remaining list is bigger than the highest number of the current sequence, just recurse with the new highest number. Otherwise, return the maximum of the current difference and the recursive call for the remainder with the current head as minimum and maximum.